# Apps Script Date issue

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am loading in a date from a cell and putting it in an array. However, I cannot use ".getHours" or .getTimeStamp. Is there a way to convert to a google time from a string if it is eligible?

Answer (score 1):

If a cell is displaying date in date format, the data returned by `getValue()` (or `getValues()` for multiple cells) **IS** a date object.

If you get something else then your spreadsheet is not formatted correctly.

You can use `.setNumberFormat('MM-dd-yyyy')` on the source cell to force the ss format or use

`new Date(cell.getValue());` to re-convert it to a date object.

Comment: This isn't what I am asking.

Comment: And what are you asking precisely?

Comment: Don't worry about it.